# Error in update in jpa

Tags: java, jpa

I have a problem when making an update when adding the horastotales when registration for the first time the code works fine but when I insert the second placed me at 0 and starts to add up wrong values ​​fields sum are attribute double this is the code with which to do this operation 
this works only when I insert the first operation if other values ​​are altered results

```
   public void crearHistorial(Equipo equipo) {
    historialDao.crearHistorial(equipo, login.getUsuario(), historial.getHorastd(), historial.getUbicacion());
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("inventarioPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
   equipo.setNumeroControl(historial.getUbicacion());
    equipoDAO.actualizarequipo(equipo, login.getUsuario());
    abrirEquipo(equipoID);
    Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE Historial c SET c.horasTrabajadas= c.horastd -" + equipo.getHorastotales() + " WHERE c.equipo.id=" + equipo.getId());
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    query.executeUpdate();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    listahist= bm.buscarHistorial(equipoID);
    for (Historial hist : listahist) {
        Query query1 = em.createQuery("UPDATE Equipo c SET c.horastotales = c.horastotales +" + hist.getHorasTrabajadas() + " WHERE c.id=" + equipo.getId());
        Query query2 = em.createQuery("UPDATE Equipo c SET c.horasmotor= c.horasmotor -" + hist.getHorasTrabajadas() + " WHERE c.id=" + equipo.getId());
        Query query3 = em.createQuery("UPDATE Equipo c SET c.horashrida= c.horashrida  -" + hist.getHorasTrabajadas() + " WHERE c.id=" + equipo.getId());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        query1.executeUpdate();
        query2.executeUpdate();
        query3.executeUpdate();
        em.getTransaction().commit(); 
    } }
```

[Show error in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbdKO.jpg)

Comment: if you say there is some error then why not present the SQL executed in the datastore? and then you work backwards from there. aka "debugging"

Comment: not in log no show error

Comment: why don't you use find->modigy->merge? For id-keyed entities such will be quite effective and much less error prone. And absolutely no need in three update queries for updating one record.

Comment: the update are used to make the rest of the fields since I got no other way

Comment: Who said look in the log for an error? I said look at the SQL executed in the datastore. DEBUG IT!

Answer (score 1):

`Equipo.id` is a primary key for `Equipo`? If so, consider switching to a more JPA-common *find→modify→merge* pattern:

```
public void crearHistorial(Equipo equipo) {
   // ...
   // put the Equipo entity in a context
   Equipo c = em.find(Equipo.class, equipo.getId()); 
   // modify the entity
   for (Historial hist : listahist) {
       c.setHorastotales(e.getHorastotales() + hist.getHorasTrabajadas());
       c.setHorasmotor(c.getHorasmotor() - hist.getHorasTrabajadas());
       c.setHorashrida(c.getHorashrida() - hist.getHorasTrabajadas());
   } 
   // update the entity in a DB
   em.getTransaction().begin();
   em.merge(c);
   em.getTransaction().commit();  
}
```

I omited the first part of a method, because it is hard to suggest meaning of names, but I hope you've caught the idea.

Comment: sasha your code is good but there is something about that when horastotales for amending it alters me all record horasTrabajadas