# After database update, results have been altered

Tags: java, jpa

I have a method to record history there have 4 mathematical functions capture the first hours worked is this

```
  Query query2 = em.createQuery("UPDATE Historial c SET c.horasTrabajadas= c.horastd -" + expediente.getHorastotales() + " WHERE c.equipo.id=" + expediente.getId());
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    query2.executeUpdate();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

This work gives me no errors but when I enter this function

```
Equipo c = em.find(Equipo.class, equipo.getId());
    for (Historial hist : listahist) {
        c.setHorastotales(c.getHorastotales() + hist.getHorasTrabajadas()
    }
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.merge(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

when the first record entry no errors but when the second the result of the subtraction me first inserted it to 0 and every time you record the last result subtracts me with previous want to know how can I prevent this from happening

Comment: You should really decide on where you're putting your business logic here. You've got subtraction code in your database update and then adding values in your code. Keep it simple in the database statement, just update the value in the database based on the value passed to that layer and do your actual logic in one place. OR simply pass a single value to the update function that then subtracts that single value from the value in the database. I would say that the first approach is better though.

Comment: Well I wonder why that could be implemented to solve this problem

Comment: E.g. change your update code to simply update the value: `UPDATE Historial c SET c.horasTrabajadas= ? WHERE c.equipo.id = ?"` and substitute the missing values. Then do your calculation logic in the application layer instead. And let your database update code simply update the value to the desired value. That way you keep your calculation code in one layer only. Much easier to debug issues with that kind of code.

Comment: if the query works fine but when I updated horastotales upsets me all horastrabajadas

Comment: Trust me. Change it to simplify your database layer to direct substitution. Then do your actual calculation logic in your application layer. You're mixing calculations in two layers at the moment and that's going to be prone to error and confusion, especially if other developers have to maintain this code.

Comment: which reason not change because I do not know how could I simplify this result

Comment: I've given you the code above. Simply update the value to a direct provided value and do your calculations elsewhere when calling that code.

Comment: if I try to change my query to a single value but I did not throw anything the only way you have reached that value was the update that show because if I remove the function horastotales the code works fine but the problem is that I mantenemer those horastotales updated

Comment: Sorry, but your English is rather broken. I'm having trouble understanding what you're saying. I can't offer much more advice than I have already. You need to separate your logical layers here otherwise your code is going to be prone to error and future confusion.

Comment: sorry friend im used google translate

Comment: Yet another variant on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117025/error-in-update-in-jpa